# React does not re-render children components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I wrote a simple task manager but it all falls apart when I try to manage all data from one point. (`TaskManager` component)
Simply, I have a `TaskManager` component which is the container of all data. Then there are `Table`'s which inside them there are `Task`'s. (All code exist down here)
I'm using [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to get behavior of an API and update the view but it doesn't show me the tasks that loaded in.

**Note**: Just to have a simple design, I added some styling with [tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/).

```js
// TaskManager.tsx
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Table, { TableInterface } from "../components/Test/Table";
import { TaskInterface } from "@/components/Test/Task";

const TaskManager: React.FC = () => {
    const [tables, setTables] = useState<TableInterface[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get<TableInterface[]>("http://127.0.0.1:5000/tables")
            .then((results) => {
                setTables(results.data);
            });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (tables.length <= 0) return;
        for (let i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
            const element = tables[i];
            if (element.tasks) continue;
            axios
                .get<TaskInterface[]>(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/tasks/${element.id}`)
                .then((results) => {
                    tables[i].tasks = results.data;
                    setTables(tables);
                });
        }
    }, [tables]);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="bg-green-800 flex space-x-6 m-5 rounded-lg">
                {tables.map((element) => {
                    const key = `${element.id}-${
                        element.tasks ? element.tasks.length : 0
                    }`;
                    return (
                        <Table
                            key={key}
                            id={element.id}
                            title={element.title}
                            tasks={element.tasks ? element.tasks : []}
                        />
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default TaskManager;
```

Inside `Table` I do nothing but showing tasks.

```js
// Table.tsx
import Task, { TaskInterface } from "./Task";

export interface TableInterface {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    tasks: TaskInterface[];
}

const Table: React.FC<TableInterface> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="font-bold text-center p-2 text-2xl">{props.title}</div>
            <div className="flex flex-col w-80 bg-slate-700 m-2 rounded-lg space-y-2 overflow-hidden">
                {props.tasks.map((item) => {
                    return <Task key={item.id} id={item.id} name={item.name} />;
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Table;
```

Inside `Task` nothing happens, just a simple render.

```js
// Task.tsx
export interface TaskInterface {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

const Task: React.FC<TaskInterface> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="bg-slate-300 w-full text-gray-900 text-lg p-2">
            {props.id}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Task;
```

#### What is the Question?

Why tasks don't show up on the screen or the more technical question is, why `Table`s do not re-render?
How to fix the problem so that tasks actually render on the screen?

This is what I see when it gets rendered.

[image: React problem, children not rendered]

Just to clarify, on my system there are 9 tasks for first column and 2 for the next one and inside react developer tools I see my data.

[image]

**Note**: This is a one month old question that I just ignored till today.
**Note**: I'm not a pro front-end developer, I'm a big noob so if you have some advises, I'll be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using setState([...oldArr, newEl]) instead of just putting data there. Im a noob too btw so let's try to resolve it together, I had the same question 2 days ago and never researched on it

Comment: Listen to me man...
It's been a month of struggle and all of a sudden you come in and with one simple answer comfort my back pain and fill me with relief.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you man.
Thank you so much but... do you know why this is happening?
I legit need an answer.

Comment: Lol this is my first answer and your response made me feel so cool :D Thanks for that!
As you reset your state, your method has that: setState(initialState => to something), so when you dont put that it just resets it to the new value. Destructuring actually includes initial thing even if you dont call arrow function. Maybe you were pulling an object and not an array, so it won't read your iterations? Idk, I just randomly pulled the thing I learned today hahah

Comment: Thanks again man, Thanks. If anyone else is reading this and can describe what caused this problem with more technical terms, I'll be happy to hear that too.

Comment: @Mahmood it seems I got it. Since we return a new array and not just a repaired old one, it refreshes the state

Comment: That actually makes sense... I was thinking the same thing too and I came to a conclusion: "If we need to actually re-render the whole component with it's children in virtual-dom, we need to refresh sate with a whole new variable and do not pass previous variable with the same memory address into it again."